# Check if the structure is Binary Tree with prolog

Tags: prolog

Using the structure :

```
tree(tip).
tree(bin(L,_,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R).
```

How to Determine whether a tree is a binary tree with every node on the left smaller then every node on the right?

What I have so far is:

```
bst(tip).
bst(tip, _, _).
bst(bin(bin(L, Ln, R), N, tip)):- N > Ln -> bst(bin(L, Ln, R)).
bst(bin(bin(L, Ln, R), N, bin(L, Rn, R))):- (
    N > Ln ->  bst(bin(L, Ln, R)); false,   
    N < Rn ->  bst(bin(L, Rn, R)); false
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you make this too complicated. We can define a predicate here to check intervals with a `null` value to check for (un)bounded intervals. For example:

```
check(null, X) :-
    !.
check(X, null) :-
    !.
check(X, Y) :-
    X < Y.
```

Next we can make a predicate that initially passes two `null`s as bounds:

```
bst(Tree) :-
    bst(Tree, null, null).
```

Now we can implement the `bst/3` predicate where for each `bin/3` compound term, we check if the value is in range, and then recursively do checks with the value as new bound:

```
bst(tip, _, _).
bst(bin(L, V1, R), V0, V2) :-
    check(V0, V1),
    check(V1, V2),
    bst(L, V0, V1),
    bst(R, V1, V2).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight variation of what Willem provided as a solution. It just handles the null branches differently:

```
bst(Tree) :-
    bst(Tree, _).

bst(tree(tip, V, tip), V).
bst(tree(tip, V, R), Rmax) :-
    bst(R, Rmax),
    V =< Rmax.
bst(tree(L, V, tip), Lmax) :-
    bst(L, Lmax),
    Lmax =< V.
bst(tree(L, V, R), R) :-
    bst(L, Lmax),
    bst(R, Rmax),
    Lmax =< V, V =< Rmax.
```